# Determine where do a function has limit.

Tags: analysis

I have to do the next exercise:

Define $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as follows:
$$f(x)=x-[x]$$ if $[x]$ is even, and $$f(x)=x-[x+1]$$ if $[x]$ is odd.

Determine those points where $f$ has a limit, and justify your conclusions.

And I have this(I do not know how to write this in latex that is why I am doin this by the next photo, thanks for your understarnding :)):

[image]

Comment: Draw the function first.

Comment: Is the ineteger part function isnt it?

Comment: @copper.hat Which function do you mean: f(x) or [x] ?

Comment: Whatever works for you!.

Comment: Can you explain me how is it possible ? :) thank you :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by '$f$ has a limit'? Do you mean continuous?

Comment: No, the definition of limit only :)

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ exists, or must it equal $f(x_0)$ or what?

Comment: well In the book it says like it is my post and is in the part of limits of function continuity is in the next chapter :)

Comment: I am sorry, I really do not know what it is you are trying to determine by '$f$ has a limit'.

Comment: Please help me is the limit definition no continiuty :)

Comment: @user162343, your definition of $[x]$ is little bit unusual.  Can you give us a few examples: $[1.2]=?$,$[2.0]=?$, $[-5.2]=?$, $[-3.0]=?$.  Usually people use $[x]$ to represent the integer part of $x$.  For example $[1.2]=[1+0.2]=1$,$[2.0]=2$, $[-5.2]=[-6.0+0.8]=-6$, $[-3.0]=-3$.

Comment: And we need to make sure that we understand 100% your notation before we can actually help you.

Comment: Well i have review my book an it says that [x] is the largest integer that is less than, or equal to x :)

Comment: example [pi]=3 :)

Comment: Then your definition of $[x]$ when $x\le -1$ is not the same as the book says. The book is correct.  For example, according to the book $[-5.6]=[-6+0.4]=-6$.  But according to you, $[-5.6]=ceiling[-5.6]=-5$

Comment: Yes I am so sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plot of your $f(x)$ vs $x$. You can see that the function values at $x=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,...$ are not well defined.

[image]

Here is a plot of $[x]$ vs. $x$ according to your book.

[image]

Comment: Then with this I can have the idea of where is the limit isnt it?

Comment: The function is well-defined everywhere.

Comment: @copper.hat. it seems to me that $f(1+0^+)=1$ and $f(1-0^+)=-1$. What is $f(1)=?$

Comment: For any even integer $f(x) =0$, for any odd integer $f(x) = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $[x] = \begin{cases} \lceil x \rceil , &x \le 1 \\
0 ,& |x| < 1 \\
\lfloor x \rfloor , & x \ge 1
\end{cases}$, we have something like

[image]

The (crude) dots show that $f(n) = 0$ when $n$ is an even integer, and $f(n) =-1$ when $n$ is an odd integer.

The function $f$ is continuous except at strictly positive odd integers and strictly negative even integers.

If by '$f$ having a limit' you mean $f$ is continuous, then this is your answer.